# Qt Quick app (or other) deploy on iOS device or emulator

Tags: c++, ios, macos, qt, qt-creator

I has Mac OS big sur 11.1, Xcode 12.3(12c33), qt 5.14.2 + qt creator 4.11.1 ( installed with online installer). I made simple project qt quick, build for macos working well, but when i try to build it for iOS emulator, I getting this error:

```
17:06:29: Running steps for project untitled...
17:06:29: Starting: "/Users/range/Qt5.14.2/5.14.2/ios/bin/qmake" /Users/range/untitled/untitled.pro -spec macx-ios-clang CONFIG+=iphonesimulator CONFIG+=simulator CONFIG+=qml_debug -after
Project ERROR: Cannot run target compiler '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++'. Output:
===================
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1"
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-ios14.3.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name - -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mframe-pointer=all -fno-strict-return -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-sdk-version=14.3 -target-cpu core2 -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=lldb -target-linker-version 609.8 -v -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.3.sdk -stdlib=libc++ -internal-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1 -internal-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.3.sdk/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.3.sdk/usr/include -internal-externc-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -Wno-reorder-init-list -Wno-implicit-int-float-conversion -Wno-c99-designator -Wno-final-dtor-non-final-class -Wno-extra-semi-stmt -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wno-quoted-include-in-framework-header -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wno-enum-enum-conversion -Wno-enum-float-conversion -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/range/Qt5.14.2/5.14.2/ios/mkspecs/features -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -stack-protector 1 -fstack-check -mdarwin-stkchk-strong-link -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fobjc-runtime=ios-14.3.0 -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -o /var/folders/j0/wkdnpcrd32x6lfr0z6rz29c40000gn/T/--aab3ee.o -x c++ -
clang -cc1 version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28) default target x86_64-apple-darwin20.2.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.3.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.3.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.3.sdk/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.x
ctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -no_deduplicate -dynamic -dylib -arch x86_64 -platform_version ios 14.3.0 14.3 -single_module -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.3.sdk -o /dev/null -v /var/folders/j0/wkdnpcrd32x6lfr0z6rz29c40000gn/T/--aab3ee.o -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.ios.a
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-609.8
BUILD 20:09:52 Nov  4 2020
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 arm64e arm64_32 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7k armv7m armv7em
Library search paths:
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.3.sdk/usr/lib
Framework search paths:
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.3.sdk/usr/lib/libc++.tbd, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.3.sdk/usr/lib/libc++.tbd (4 slices)
ld: building for iOS, but linking in object file built for iOS Simulator, file '/var/folders/j0/wkdnpcrd32x6lfr0z6rz29c40000gn/T/--aab3ee.o' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
===================
Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?
17:06:30: The process "/Users/range/Qt5.14.2/5.14.2/ios/bin/qmake" exited with code 3.
Error while building/deploying project untitled (kit: Эмулятор Qt 5.14.2 for iOS)
When executing step "qmake"
17:06:30: Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

[image]

Accordingly I can’t generate project for xcode and build app for real device, since the same error occurs.

My sets:
[image]

[image]
Profiles:
[image]
Compilers:
[image]

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. You need to find all files called as "toolchain.prf" in qt instalation directory and change this code:

```
defineTest(qtCompilerError) {
    !cross_compile: \
        what =
    else: host_build: \
        what = " host"
    else: \
        what = " target"
    qtToolchainError("Cannot run$$what compiler '$$1'. Output:", $$2, \
                     "Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?")
}
```

to this code:

```
defineTest(qtCompilerError) {
    # empty
}
```

After this everything works fine on ios and ios-emulator.

Comment: Hello buddy, Thanks you very much!! I had the same problem and I fixed it temporarily using your hack. I would really like to know why Qt is throwing this error, did you found something about it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't find cause. But this solution work is great.